# Segmentation fault with linked list when i assign a value

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * next ;
}Node ;

typedef Node * List ;

int main(void){

    List *l;
    int a = 2;
    int b =12;
    l = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*l) -> data = a;
    printf("%d\n", (*l)->data);
    (*l) = (*l)->next;
    l = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*l) -> data = b;
    printf("%d\n", (*l) ->data);
    (*l) = (*l)->next;
    (*l) = NULL;

}
```

Hi guys!
I am writing a simple code with linked list, my goal is to write into the list 2 values `a` and `b`. The problem is that the application goes in segmentation fault probably in this line `(*l) -> data = a;`.
I know there are a lot of topic similar to this, but anyway I cannot fix my problem.

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After this

```
l = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Pointer `l` received the address for something of `Node` size.

This dereferences the pointer twice, i.e. it uses the pointed-to content as a pointer, dereferences it and access who-knows-where, which triggers the segfault (if you are lucky).

```
(*l) -> data = a;
```

Once is sufficient:

```
l -> data = a;
```

or

```
(*l).data = a;
```

This would fix the segfault.

However, `l` is declared as pointer-to-(typedefhidden-pointer-to-Node).
That declaration matches dereferencing twice.

To clean that up, I propose to declare `l` as nonhidden pointer to `Node`.

```
Node *l;
```

As far as I can tell, that should be appropriate for the codes purpose.

Or declare as hidden pointer to `Node`, i.e. as `List`.

```
List l;
```

Maybe you actually need a double pointer for unmentioned requirements.
But in that case please make a separate question, with code which demonstrates that need. It will take more explanation about two levels of mallocing, matching the two levels of pointer.

After fixing the segfault described in this question, your code will have foreseeable problems, based on faulty handling of linked lists. Please also make a  separate question on those problems, they are unrelated to the pointer-type nesting depth mismatches discussed here.

Comment: So essentially when the pointer try to access (*l) -> data , it doesn't know where it is so it cause the segmentation fault ? I've tried to replace that line with the one you suggest but i can't even compile it.

Comment: In which way does compiling fail? What error message?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer Nice edit. Thanks for mindreading correctly.

Comment: if i write "l -> data = a" it tells "expression must have pointer to struct or union type) .
if i write "(*l).data -> a" it tells "expressione must have struct or union type"

Comment: It is not about causing segfault because of not knowing where. It is more like "I trust you that I really should write there... Ouch! Ouch! Ouch!".

Comment: I edited. I am afraid that I am getting closer to the (now deleted) answer by @KeineLust, especially in combination with the comments.